# Bash - for i in cat?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm not a bash scriptor, so this is no doubt a very simple question.

I have a bash script throwing an error. It looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in (cat /root/list.txt)
do
        doSomething
done
```

The error is on the second line, related to the curly brackets. So it seems curly brackets shouldn't be here... in which case, what should line 2 look like?

The script is supposed to read each line out of /root/list.txt and then doSomething with this (I removed the actual command for this example.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Probably

```
for i in $(cat /root/list.txt)
```

Comment: Probably, or certainly? Because if I run this script incorrectly it could mess up a lot of work.

Comment: In that case you should definitely test it by doing something benign in the loop body (such as `echo`ing `i`).

Comment: As above; it's hard for me to guess details although that's the most likely intended code, but any time something could have drastic effects it's a very good idea to run it initially stubbed (with leading `echo`s etc.) and verify its behavior. For a fixed script you may want to implement a `--dry-run` option to do this. Also note the other answer; one of the uncertainties is that `for` will word-split, not line-split, and I have no way of knowing which is correct in your application.

Comment: Word split would be fine. Here is the actual command then: `sshpass -p 'PasswordRemoved' scp *-install.sh -l root -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyCheck ${i}:` the list.txt is a list of IP addresses to copy the files to.

Comment: The `$` I added told the shell to run the `cat` and word-split it into a list for `for`; without that, the command would be meaningless (assuming that the actual intent was not literal parameters `cat /root/list.txt` which seems highly unlikely). Given that, as far as I know it should be correct. (I would be more pedantic about both the files to be copied and the destination, but that's just me.)

Answer (score 14):

You should not use a for loop to read lines. [Use a while read loop instead.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r i; do
  doSomething
done < /root/list.txt
```

Comment: Totally agreed!

Answer (score 2):

try

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat /root/list.txt`
do
    doSomething
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your bash script with :

```
set -x
```

Use this :

```
for line in $(cat /etc/fstab)
do 
   echo $line ; sleep 1
done
```

Or this :

```
while read line
do
    echo $line ; sleep 1
done < /etc/fstab
```

Note : line is variable